# What is the best practice for loading different objects into UIViews Swift

Tags: ios, swift, uiview

I am a high school student working on a program that connects to a database and displays information in an application. This part works. I would like to have a single `UIViewController` that loads different pieces of information based on a `UISegmentControl` selection in an `UIView`.

What is the best way to do this?

As the user selects the segment information inside the `UIView` will change and be loaded with different pieces of information from the database.

As I choose the map label, which will be one of the options in the `UISegmentControl` I want the `UIView` to display the map and if the user switches back, I want the `UIView` to switch back to other information.

Potentially, there could be up to five different segments in the `UISegmentControl`

I had an image of an example storyboard, but It would not let me post it.

Comment: Do you have a specific reason for wanting to switch between views rather than view controllers? It seems you could do this with a tab bar controller instead of using one view controller.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do almost anything you want. But, the problem I see here is you will have to manage lots of views for each segment and your view controller will be super huge. Looks like you are learning iOS so I suggest to design your app in a way that you don't have to do crazy coding! Maybe you can navigate to different view controllers for each segment that you want to toggle using UISegmentedControl?

But if you insist on doing it the way you described. You can define separate views for each segment which is a child view of the main view. Based on what segment you have selected you can toggle the active child view in and out of the main view. For that, you can use some kind of animation too.

There are many ways, hope this helps.